# How to avoid properties to be persist in MongoDb

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-hateoas

I am using hateoas for implementing links in my repositories.So my Customer Class extends ResourceSupport which has private `final List<Link> links;` and in constructor

```
public ResourceSupport() {
        this.links = new ArrayList<Link>();
    }
```

So when I am saving customer entity using Mongo template `mongoTemplate.save(customer);` 
So when I see the documents in Mongo db it shows

```
{ 
_id:"objectid(57vsdsjdsk),
firstName:"Yamini",
lastName:"Tyagi"
links as empty Array List(initialized in constructor)
}
```

So how would I avoid links to be persisted in Mongo database?

Please help on this?

Comment: Nobody has an answer to this?  :-(  I have the same exact problem.

Answer (score 0):

I have overloaded the get method of that property in my child class and marked that as @Transient
Using the @Transient annotation that particular property will not save in Database. Hope this will help

```
 @Override
   @Transient
   public java.util.List<org.springframework.hateoas.Link> getLinks() {
        return super.getLinks();
   }
```